# Proving that an index does not belong to Optimal Sub Interval Sum

Tags: algorithm

Suppose the input to the maximum sub interval problem is an array A. For an index i, if the best sum among all the sub intervals ending in i is negative, prove that the optimum sub interval does not include i.

Comment: any programming language? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Not using programming language, need a mathematical proof

Comment: Have you tried Mathematics site?